# Show that the unbounded region determined by a closed curve is doubly connected

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Show that the unbounded region determined by a closed curve is doubly connected.

I am not sure what to do here. I proved that a bounded component determined by the curve is simoly connected, so that I only have to show that the union of such bounded components are connected. But how do I show this? The below proof just assumes this but this is not immediately clear to me.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijHJB.jpg)

Comment: Do you consider a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$? What does "doubly connected" mean in that context?

Comment: @PaulFrost A doubly connected region  $K$ has two components in $\mathbb C - K$; for example, the unit circle has two components, one the unit disk and the other the region with infinity.